# Getting Facebook user details in Swift with PFFacebookUtilsV4 Cocoapods

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, parse-platform, cocoapods

I'm having some difficulties obtaining a user's Facebook details, such as name and email.

Upon searching through various questions, it seems the method to call is `FBRequestConnection`. I don't have access to that function. I'm using CocoaPods to deal with my 3rd party library integration, and here is my podfile:

> pod 'Parse', '1.7.5'
>   pod 'ParseUI', '1.1.4'
>   pod 'FBSDKShareKit'
>   pod 'ParseFacebookUtilsV4'

Either ParseFacebookUtilsV4 does not contain FBRequestConnection, or it has since been deprecated.

Can anyone direct me the method to query Facebook for a user's name and email?

Comment: Instead of

#import <ParseFacebookUtils/PFFacebookUtils.h>
use :

#import <ParseFacebookUtilsV4/PFFacebookUtils.h>

Comment: I did that import correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use FBSDKGraphRequest in facebooksdkv4 to get user's info (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/upgrading-4.x)

```
var fbRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: nil)
fbRequest.startWithCompletionHandler({ (FBSDKGraphRequestConnection, result, error) -> Void in

    if (error == nil && result != nil) {
        let facebookData = result as! NSDictionary //FACEBOOK DATA IN DICTIONARY
        let userEmail = (facebookData.objectForKey("email") as? String)
        let firstName = (facebookData.objectForKey("first_name") as? String)
        let lastName = (facebookData.objectForKey("last_name") as? String)
    }
})
```

Comment: I have var permissions = [ "public_profile", "email", "user_friends" ] but i'm not able to get the email, first_name etc.

Comment: I fixed it. You need to have parameters:["fields":"id,email,name,first_name,last_name"]